# Setting up groovy SDK on Intellij 2017.1

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I'm trying to run Spock tests with my project in IntelliJ 2017.1 community ed. While editing my spec file I get the error msg "Cannot resolve spock" on the import line with a "Configure Groovy SDK" link. When I click on that link I get the "Setup Library" dialog. It has a "Use library" folder search. So I locate my groovy-2.4.10 SDK folder and press Ok. Then I get this error msg:

> Looks like Groovy distribution in specified path is broken. Cannot
>   determine version.

I've checked and double-checked the groovy SDK folder. It's a complete groovy SDK folder as un-zipped from the prestine download I did from http://groovy-lang.org/download.html.

So I'm at a loss as to where to go next. Anyone run into this with IntelliJ 2017.1 community ed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43041188/104891.

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder. The 2017.1.1 seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CrazyCoder's comment to my question is the answer. Upgrade to 2017.1.1 version of IDEA solved the issue.

It's a known issue:

- [IDEA-170022](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170022) Cannot create Groovy project, because cannot create Groovy library (2.4.10 version)

As a workaround you can use Groovy 2.4.9 or rename `groovy-2.4.10.jar` to `groovy-2.4.9.jar`.

The problem is fixed for IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 and 2016.3.6 versions.